# Do there exist measurable transformations which are recurrent over spaces of infinite measure?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am trying to find a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{B})$, with measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(X)=\infty$, and with a corresponding measure preserving transformation $T:X\rightarrow X$ such that $T$ is recurrent over $X$.  That is, $T$ is such that for all $B\in \mathcal{B}$, there exists infinitely many $n>0$ such that $T^{n}(B) \cap B \not= \emptyset$.

Does such a dynamical system exist?  If so, can you provide example or reference? If no such system exists, is there a particular reason (ie. it is not possible, or one has not been found)?

Comment: What about real line with Lebesgue measure and the map $T(c)=-c$?

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho ok that certainly answers the question.  Are there any more complex examples though, ie a map that is topologically transitive instead of recurrent then?  If you would like, I could edit the question, and you can answer and I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related to, what is called, infinite ergodic theory. There are many interesting examples. An excellent reference to learn about this is the book of [Jon Aaronson "An introduction to infinite ergodic theory"](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-50)